How can I play multiple mp3 files without any gap in Rust?
I have some MP3 files downloaded from SoundCloud and I want to play them in sequence but whenever I've tried to do it in Rodio for example, it always had a really small gap between the audios.
use cpal::{traits::HostTrait, SampleRate, SupportedStreamConfig};
use rodio::{Decoder, Source};
use std::{fs::File, u64};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let default_device = cpal::default_host()
        .default_output_device()
        .ok_or("No default audio output device is found.")?;
    let (_stream, stream_handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_from_device_config(&default_device, 
        SupportedStreamConfig::new(1, SampleRate(44100), cpal::SupportedBufferSize::Range { min: 5000, max: 35000 }, cpal::SampleFormat::U64)
    )?;
    let sink = rodio::Sink::try_new(&stream_handle).unwrap();
    let data1 = Decoder::new(File::open("1.mp3").unwrap()).unwrap().buffered();
    let data2 = Decoder::new(File::open("2.mp3").unwrap()).unwrap().buffered();
    let data3 = Decoder::new(File::open("3.mp3").unwrap()).unwrap().buffered();
    sink.append(data1);
    sink.append(data2);
    sink.append(data3);
    
    
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(u64::MAX));
    Ok(())
}

I added the Rodio dependency as such:
rodio = {version="0.17",features=["symphonia-all"]}

Anyone knows how can I solve this problem? Thanks
Tried using the minimp3 backend, using other library like Kira but with even less success because I didn't know how to play the files in sequence.
